# Trouble installing Lagarith Lossless Codec (Codec Removal?)

Tags: codec

I had been using the [Lagarith Lossless Codec](http://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html) with [camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) on Windows XP Pro SP3 for a little while before I switched to Ubuntu. Now I'm back trying to do something on windows and the codec is now missing. I tried to install it via the .exe and even manually with the .inf but it's not being listed by camstudio as installed.

I'm wondering if one of the other codecs I installed might have messed with it and yet some of the files are still fine so whatever method the installers use to check for existing files before install is returning positive and not re-installing it.

How can I get Lagarith to work again? Maybe I need to know how to uninstall codecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to uninstall codecs. You just need to unregister them, which lets you re-register them later on.

A good tool to use is [**GSpot**](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm):

Run it, wait for all codecs to be detected, and select the menu item System->List Codecs.
Sort the codecs by 'Format' by clicking the column header. The driver file is listed, and is to be found in System32.
Go down the list and see if you have multiple handlers for the same format. There are several types of codec-handlers (splitters etc.), so be careful you have the right one.
Right-click on a codec and select Un-Register to disable it (you can Re-Register it the same way). Playback for the media encoding type will now be the next one in the list for that media type (if others are installed).

Another utility that can be used for the same purpose is [InstalledCodec](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html) by NirSoft.

Another way to list all the codecs is by using Windows Media Player:

1. Open Windows Media Player
2. Use the menu item Help->About Windows Media Player.
3. Click on the "Technical Support Information" link in the About Window.

I suggest creating a system restore point before doing these operations.

Comment: I thought that the bounty automatically went to you at the end. Instead I caused you to lose it and now I can't end the question. To make up I read many of your other posts and upvoted all the good ones. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Xeoncross: you're welcome, and thanks for your efforts.